# Is there a way to pause/resume particular TCP connection?

Tags: networking, iptables, tcp, ipfw, keepalive

I'm playing online game that matches me against random players. I found out that when I unplug my Ethernet cable, I have a minute to decide do I want this match to count.

If things go wrong, I just restart the game and start over.
If things go the way I planned, I plug the cable back in and continue.

The problem is, more often than not I need two minutes to make up my mind, but the game disconnects me after 60 seconds (I get "Connection lost" error)

The question is, how can I prevent a connection from timing out?

I assume that if I let keep-alive packets go through, but pause actual data packets, I will be able to pause and resume tcp connection on demand, but I'm not sure if it is possible with a common firewall software like iptables or ipfw, or I should go with the MITM?

The game uses SSL encryption over a standard TCP socket.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The timeout is almost certainly on receiving the actual data the server is waiting for, not on the TCP connection. This is how timeouts are typically implemented. There are no TCP timeouts that are in the 60 second range, so this is almost certainly *not* a TCP timeout and can't be changed by manipulations at the TCP level.

Comment: I know we arent suppose to +1, but +1 to you

Comment: I'll mark this as a correct answer - there are no 60 second timeouts in TCP. But there is still something else involved. If I unplug my cable while downloading file via HTTP, download resumes instantly if I plug it back in in less than 60 seconds, otherwise it becomes stuck

Comment: Maybe you have a router that tries to keep the connection alive to a certain point.

Comment: You are most certainly right, looks like some intermediate network point is responsible for the dropped/stuck connection, probably my router (I'm behind NAT). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### No.

Once a TCP connection is closed, it cannot be resumed, at the network level.  The application must support a resume feature, which retains state over a new TCP connection.

You could submit a feature request to the developers of the game you're playing.  Be sure to explain that you want a feature that makes it easier for you to cheat.

Comment: You missed the point, I'm asking how to prevent the connection from timing out. Sure it can't be resumed once it was closed on the server side.